# What does “rock on Wayne” mean?

Tags: idioms

Could anyone tell me what does *rock on Wayne* mean? The context is

> Classes don't usually have data, but if they do, rock on Wayne.

Comment: GR: http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/rock-on

Comment: [Party on, Garth. Party on, Wayne.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oe30habM0ls&t=5m41s)

Comment: lol. Its a clever cultural reference for those of us who were watching American Movies (and Saturday Night Live) in the 90's. For everyone else, I guess it was just put in there to confuse you. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user is most likely paraphrasing the character Garth from “Wayne's World,” a sketch which began on *Saturday Night Live* and was adapted into a feature-length film.

*Party on, Wayne... Party on, Garth* is an oft-repeated mutual affirmation between the two lead characters, Wayne Campbell (portrayed by Mike Myers) and Garth Algar (portrayed by Dana Carvey).

Comment: Thank you,but I'm still not very sure how to translate the whole sentence,does rock on Wayne mean just do it directly?

Answer (score 1):

The meaning in both cases would be "keep doing what you're doing". *Party on Garth!* - I approve of what you're doing, keep doing it! *Classes don't usually have data, but if they do, rock on Wayne.* - If you do find a class with data, don't worry about it, do what you'd do with a data-less class!